# Subdomain redirection is causing an error in apache

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I am redirecting https://username.mywebsite.com/ to https://mywebsite.com/username using this redirection

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://mywebsite.com/%1

OR 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^([^.]+)\.mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/%1 [L,NC,QSA,R]
```

But I get this error when I try my page using subdoamin:

> There is a problem with this website’s security certificate.
>
> The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.
>
> Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to trick you or intercept any data you send to the server.
>
> We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website.
>
> Recommended iconClick here to close this webpage.
>
> Not recommended iconContinue to this website (not recommended).

I can click "Continue to this website (not recommended). " and my browser ignore the error but this is not user friendly.

I have unlimited users and my SSL is wildcard . I don't want users get this error :(

I have added *.mywebsite.com to the routing

Here is may ssl config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mywebsite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite.com

        RewriteEngine on

        SSLEngine on
        #SSLProxyEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/markethive.com/mywebsite.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/markethive.com/mywebsite.key
        SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/markethive.com/mywebsite.ca-bundle

        LogLevel info
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/markethive.com_ssl/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/markethive.com_ssl/ssl.log  combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mean your SSL certificate is not a valide certificate (may be you self signed it ?).

- To obtain a SSL certificate you have to find a SSL provider and get your certificate & Key from them. It will cost you money to buy a SSL certificate.
- You need a certificate for each subdomain too.
- If you have an official certificate, try to correct the time on your client computer.
- Check your SSL configuration, it is maybe not correct
- If you are using a wildcard SSL, you need to set your certifiate to default to be able to set it for each SSL site :

---

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443> 
..
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/markethive.com/mywebsite_com.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/markethive.com/mywebsite_com.key 
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/markethive.com/mywebsite_com.ca-bundle
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
...
#your server conf
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sorry it is no that. I have purchased my SSl certificate

Comment: Then post your SSL config cause your certificate isn't used by Apache, so you may have an error in it. An check Apache log too.

Comment: I have configured it in Apache config

Comment: I have unlimited users and my SSL is wildcard

Comment: Do you have a certificate for the domain and the sub domain ? can you post your SSL config ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32005/discussion-between-fury-and-froggiz).